# Yii 1: which is the difference from sqlsrv and mssql as db driver?

Tags: yii

I'm referring [to this lines](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/db/CDbConnection.php#L435) of the source code for `CDbConnection` class:

```
        if($driver==='mssql' || $driver==='dblib')
            $pdoClass='CMssqlPdoAdapter';
        elseif($driver==='sqlsrv')
            $pdoClass='CMssqlSqlsrvPdoAdapter';
```

My question is: which is the differences from mssql/dblib and sqlsrv? When use one instead of the other?

Comment: Make sure you visit part 2: [difference between sqlsrv and mssql](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlsrv for windows

dblib/mssql for linux/mac os

so configuration will also differ slightly.

sqlsrv:

```
[
'class'            => 'CDbConnection',
'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=db_name',
'username'         => 'root',
'password'         => 'root',
'charset'          => 'utf8',
'tablePrefix'      => 'tbl_',
]
```

dblib/mssql:

```
[
'class'            => 'CDbConnection',
'connectionString' => 'dblib:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8',
'username'         => 'root',
'password'         => 'root',
'tablePrefix'      => 'tbl_',
]
```